# background transparent in circular image

Tags: css, angular, canvas

[image]

hello, I'm using the ngx-img-cropper to make a cutout in circular mode, I'm using css to make the result circular the question is that I need the outline outside the circle to be transparent and not fill the color like the image above , I need that when saving the image, only the round part that was selected will appear and the transparent background.

```
  data: any;
  cropperSettings: CropperSettings;

  @ViewChild("cropper",undefined) cropper:ImageCropperComponent;

  constructor() {
    this.cropperSettings               = new CropperSettings();
    this.cropperSettings.rounded       = true;
    this.cropperSettings.width         = 250;
    this.cropperSettings.height        = 250; 
    this.cropperSettings.croppedWidth  = 250;
    this.cropperSettings.croppedHeight = 250;
    this.cropperSettings.canvasWidth   = 350;
    this.cropperSettings.canvasHeight  = 350;
    this.cropperSettings.fileType      = "image/png";
    this.data = {};
  }


    .rounded {
      border-radius: 50% !important;
     -moz-border-radius: 50% !important;
     -webkit-border-radius: 50% !important;
     display: inline-block;
     object-fit:cover;
     text-align: center;
     width: 250px;
     height: 250px;
    }
```

Comment: PNG image has transparency built into it. So you could just use the image and none of that code. Or you could use the border radius if you want to make a square image look like a circle. the Cropper settings look a bit extreme for a circle that can be done with CSS. You dont want to be doing the same thing twice and just adding load to the page when you could have just done it with CSS

Comment: I think you dont get it my question brow

Comment: like this website that crop an image circular and when download it, the background is transparent https://crop-circle.imageonline.co/#circlecropresult

Comment: @Andrew here is the idea https://crop-circle.imageonline.co/#circlecropresult